# How do you develop againsts a forked repo?

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php

I have a Laravel app that im working on and plan to use the following repo via composer:
https://github.com/WhatArmy/FedexRest

I want to implement some of the features that its missing, so I forked the repo.

In my composer.json I added the following, so that I am now using my version of the composer package from my fork on github:

```
{
"type": "vcs",
"url": "https://github.com/bmecler/fedexrest"
}
```

What is the best way to keep developing in my own version of the repo? Right now I am thinking that I would develop directly in vendor/WhatArmy/FedexRest so that I can see changes directly in my Laravel app as im making them.

But then Im not actually working out of the git repo and cant track my changes and commit them back..

If I clone my forked git repo to develop on it locally, then its not inside my Laravel app for me to easily develop against..

My other thought would be to somehow clone my forked repo into /vendor/WhatArmy/FedexRest and then maybe I could develop and commit back to the repo..

What is best practice here? Should I be developing my fork independently from my Laravel app? I would assume I should.. but it feels like that doesnt make it easy for me to see and test my changes in my Laravel app.

Comment: The more I read, I suspect my development of the fork should be completely independent of the app I plan to utilize it in? I dont even need a webserver, just write classes and php unit test them from command line?

Comment: You should be developing independently, because it is a package, so think like if  you did not have a Laravel project ready to use it. You still have to test it, so create tests (see my StackOverflow profile for some help) and use the [`orchestral/testbench`](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) to be able to run the tests simulating you have a Laravel app. Do read the documentation, it will help: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/packages

Answer (score -1):

This can not be clearly answered, you will find pros/cons for the different ways and every project is different.

However, there is no hard requirement here to not start the way you started and to not switch later to another (local) fork.

But first things first: Using the VCS composer repository as you have in your question is outlined in [Loading a package from a VCS repository (Composer docs)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) with the example of a bugfix branch.

In general, you have already forked the original repo on Github, and when you make use of it as composer vcs repository, composer will clone your fork and you will find the clone in the vendor folder. There you can also commit changes and push them back to your github fork (origin), and then file pull-request (upstream).

All of this works already. So you don't need to decide about that, because this workflow comes with composer, git + github is well supported by it. Your assumption in the question that you can't yet commit and push your changes is wrong. You can already. Composer even guards non-committed changes and there is a vcs "backup" in composer cache that composer will take care to sync with your github fork.

---

Now you further ask if not *"my development of the fork should be completely independent of the app"*. Should it? Isn't it already?

- You already have an independent fork on Github
- You already can commit, push and file pull-requests

and:

- Your development of the fork will *never* be completely independent to your app.

The reason why you forked is because of your app. Your app is the parent, and this is how you will grow that system. But the library upstream will also likely not go away.

So as so often it depends. These are your options to "upgrade":

1. Develop independently with your fork on Github. Create issues and file pull requests and get your changes upstream. Use the package via packagist again (or your development VCS depending on how fast upstream does releases).

   This is *normally* the best way. You benefit from your own as well as from upstream changes, and when you continue to use the vcs repository of your fork, you don't have to wait for your own (downstream) changes.
2. Use a local clone of your github repository - independent to app - as composer path repository.

   This works, you just provide your local path to it instead of the remote URL and switch from vcs to [path](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path).

   If you have support for symbolic links, you will find not a checkout (copy) in the vendor folder then but a symbolic link to the local fork.

   This requires you have a build process which creates an artifact that contains all the code of your app, incl. vendor. You then put that artifact under CI and if all green deploy it.

   This variant therefore has higher setup requirements. The development workflow in both the app and the library is still relatively fast though. But you have to manage two projects effectively as they are independent. That means you will potentially diverge more from upstream for the dependency and that is bad as the most effective process you can only make with upstream.